# Add objects to List of current user asp.net mvc using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, model-view-controller, entity

I have an ASP.NET MVC application I am working on, the user can login/register as either an admin, personal account, or company..  The company and personal models have properties that are Lists of other objects.  I need to know how I can add something to individual logged in's list, and update it in the database

The method I am working on in the controller..

```
 public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Date,Location,StartTime,EndTime,IsPublic")] Event @event)
        {
            string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            ApplicationUser currentUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == currentUserId);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Events.Add(@event);
                db.SaveChanges();
                if (User.IsInRole("Company"))
                {
                    Company CompanyHosting = db.Companies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == currentUser.Email);
                    var company = from e in db.PersonalUsers
                                 where e.Email == currentUser.Email
                                 select e;
                    foreach (var item in company)
                    {
                        item.HostedEvents.Add(@event);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                else if (User.IsInRole("PersonalUser"))
                {
                    PersonalUser PersonHosting = db.PersonalUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == currentUser.Email);
                    var person = from e in db.PersonalUsers
                                 where e.Email == currentUser.Email
                                 select e;
                    foreach (var item in person)
                    {
                        item.HostedEvents.Add(@event);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(@event);
        }
```

And The Model for PersonalUser.. Company looks almost identical..

```
public class PersonalUser
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool AcceptsTextNotifications { get; set; }
    public bool AcceptsEmailNotifications { get; set; }
    public List<PersonalUser> PeopleIFollow = new List<PersonalUser>();
    public List<PersonalUser> PeopleThatFollowMe = new List<PersonalUser>();
    public List<Company> CompaniesIFollow = new List<Company>();
    public List<Company> CompaniesThatFollowMe = new List<Company>();
    public List<Event> HostedEvents = new List<Event>();
    public List<Event> EventsGoingTo = new List<Event>();

    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public string ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

And Model for Event..

```
   public class Event
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string StartTime { get; set; }
        public string EndTime { get; set; }
        public bool IsPublic { get; set; }

        public List<PersonalUser> PersonalInvited = new List<PersonalUser>();
    }
```

Why is it that the lines 
    item.HostedEvents.Add(@event);
    db.SaveChanges();
do not update the database, inserting that event into the Personal or Company models List HostedEvents??

Comment: Do you get any error? If not, have you debugged to see if your event parameter getting values?

Comment: @MukeshModhvadiya no errors, event parameters gets correct information.  var item also gets correct information.

Comment: You are selecting records from PersonalUsers in both if and else with different names company and person.

Comment: @MukeshModhvadiya thanks for the heads up! Won't fix the code though

Answer (score 0):

You are just adding event to EventList of item, but not telling DbContext to update the item. Change it as below :

```
foreach (var item in person)
{
    item.HostedEvents.Add(@event);
    db.PersonalUsers.Update(item);
}
db.SaveChanges();
```